# CloudWatch metrics query failed: InvalidClientTokenId

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana, amazon-cloudwatch

Getting this error while trying to connect grafana to cloudwatch in opt-in ap-east-1 region. I'm using access & secret key with Assume Role ARN witch work fine in other regions.
Found similar issue https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/48267#issuecomment-1119592852
but setting `AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS=regional` env var on grafana server does not help.
May be i'm doing something wrong, please any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of researching and test, i found answer. Use aws admin user account of current region. Unpossible to use AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS=regional variable in deb/rpm grafana but for example in container it